# fallo al buscar elemento en cola de tipo Queue

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

hola buenas hace rato avia publicado una pregunta relacinado a esto y una persona hablamente me dio una idea de como hacerlo pero pasa que me tira un error que dice

**java.lang.ClassCastExeption: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to clases.Datos**

mi idea es sacar de una cola de tipo Queue(la cola es de objetos)

```
               Queue cola = new LinkedList();
```

esta como esta en una clase aparte que se llama cola pero lo pongo para que vean que es de tipo lista enlazada

```
      datos = (Datos) cola.cola;

       ComboBox_cursos.addItem(datos.getNombre());
    
         while (datos.getNombre() != null) {

      ComboBox_cursos.addItem(datos.getNombre());    

    }
```

mi idea es pasar la cola al tipo de datos donde estan almacenados los get, entonces con un while ee recorro que mientras datos.getNombre que es el dato que quiero imprimir sea diferente de null se imprima dentro e un conbobox, osea mientras sigan aviendo datos se siga ciclando peroooo no me funciona, agradesco cualquier ayuda.

entonces el punto es que cada objeto de la cola tiene un nombre y ocupo imprimir un un combobox solo los nombres de cada objeto

tambien intente esto

```
        for (int i = 0; i<cola.cola.size() ; i++) {
        
          datos = (Datos) cola.cola;
          
           ComboBox_cursos.addItem(datos.getNombre());    
          
        
    }
```

pero dice que hay un error de casteo con datos

pero dice que hay un error de casteo

Comment: una linkedList no tiene nada que ver con una Queue.. no vas a poder transformar una en otra asi como asi...

Comment: y no entiendo para que usar una cola.. entendes para que sirve una cola?

Comment: ya lo resolvi amigo, ee podia imprimir los datos sin necesidad del parseo, gracias igual por tu respuesta tan amable